# ¿Es posible hacer un popover siempre centrado en la pagina, algo asi como un modal pero on hover?

Tags: bootstrap

[¿como adapto el tamaño del popover de bootstrap al tamaño del contenido?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/52785/como-adapto-el-tama%C3%B1o-del-popover-de-bootstrap-al-tama%C3%B1o-del-contenido)

dentro de ese link hay un popover adaptado al width 100%, mi pregunta es, si es posible que ese mismo popover se muestre al centro de la pantalla siempre

Comment: Hola Enrique, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. En este sitio se ayuda con problemas como el que planteas, pero has de mostrar tus intentos. Prueba a hacerlo y si no sale , explicanos qué errores o problemas concretos tienes para poder decierte como mejorarlo. Mira [ask] y [mcve] para más info.  Un saludo.

Comment: @Enrique Solis Podrias poner el codigo que ya tienes

Comment: ¿Qué tiene de malo utilizar un modal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En realidad es muy fácil (si entendí bien lo que pretendes), pero te aclaro, que probablemente me gane unos puntos negativos en esta pregunta por responderte, **siendo que las has formulado de manera incorrecta**, ya que no proporcionas al menos como tienes tu estructura html, si has intentado hacerlo o un ejemplo en imagen de lo que quieres lograr.

Al grano, solo necesitas usar `position: fixed` en el contenedor del **pop up** y posicionarlo al centro dinámicamente, así:

```
.popup{
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate( -50%, -50%);
}
```

Aquí un ejemplo con 2 estructuras html, una con el contenido popup dentro del popover y otra estando en la misma posición jerárquica:

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box; margin: 0; padding: 0;
  font-family: arial;}

.pop-over{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.5em;
  background: whitesmoke;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
}

.popup{
padding: 0.5em 1em;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate( -50%, 0);
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 10;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1em 0 rgba(0,0,0,.2);  
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  pointer-events: none;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all ease .3s;
}

.pop-over:hover .popup,
.pop-over:hover + .popup{
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);  
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<label class="pop-over">
  Texto 01
  <div class="popup">
    Contenido
  </div>
</label>

<label class="pop-over">
  Texto 02
</label>
<div class="popup">
  Contenido
</div>
```

Ahora, que funcione o no, depende de varias cosas, tu estructura html, el css que tienes que sobreescribir, si estas queriendo una solución más con javascript o si se ha entendido bien tu problema. Cualquier cosa dejame tu comentario. Éxitos!

Comment: Disculpa por formular la pregunta de manera incorrecta, la verdad es la primera vez que hacia una consulta y en la necesidad del momento no me preocupe de enterarme como es el formato de pregunta, te agradezco demasiado por tu respuesta, la verdad me sirvió muchísimo.